# Pass node.js option via grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

When I start grunt on the command line, how can I pass an argument to the node process?

In concrete, I'd like to pass the option --expose-gc to node running grunt.
The command I run is:

```
grunt mocha:mytests
```

I want to achieve, that my mocha tests get the garbage collection interface exposed.

If that is of any help: the grunt file section looks like this:

```
myTest: {
    src: [
        'mocha.hooks/*.spec.js',
        'build/ch.actifsource.*/**/test/*.spec.js',
        'mocha.hooks/*.spec.server.js',
        'build/ch.actifsource.*/**/test/*.spec.server.js'
    ],
    options: {
        timeout: 500,
        logErrors: true
    },
    ignore: [
        './src/**/RegisterResourceTypes.js'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The API's for the various grunt mocha plugins do not provide an option to pass `--expose-gc`, including this [one](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha).

You could install [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) instead and configure it to run the same mocha command as you would via the [CLI](https://mochajs.org/#usage).

Your *grunt-shell* `command` would be:

```js
// ...
shell: {
    myTest: {
        command: './node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -t 500 -gc path/to/files'
    }
}
// ...
```

The `path/to/files` part should be replaced with your `src` files.

Note, the command runs local *mocha* via the `bin` folder so you also need to install [mocha](https://mochajs.org/):

`$ npm i -D mocha`

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer. It's a pitty, that it is not possible to pass such options. However, I will not mark this as accepted answer atm, as I still hope, that someone comes up with a more integrated solution.

Comment: On a related note... in the `grunt-mocha` project repo (on GitHub) there are several requests/issues for supporting other _mocha_ CLI options in the open [issues](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha/issues). However as `--expose-gc` is a _mocha_ CLI option and as the project owner mentions in this [reply](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha/issues/136#issuecomment-62059400)  - the "plugin does not use the command line mocha". So I'd be surprised if there's a more integrated solution.

Comment: So how can I run grunt itself with this option enabled? It's really just for tests, where I want to explicitely trigger the gc for doing runtime checks for memory leaks. (Aka "make sure, that all instances removed their references on cleanup")